# Why isn't my code looking for non-letters? (Regular expressions)

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String naming;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name: ");
    naming = input.nextLine();  
    input.close();

    //**
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(naming);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[^a-zA-Z]");
    boolean check = matcher.find();
    if (check) {
      System.out.println("Invalid name entered");
      //**
    } else {
      System.out.print("continue");
    }
  }
}
```

Between the `**` is the part I'm stuck on. This program is supposed to ask for your name, and if you enter anything that's not a letter, then it will say "Invalid name entered." But instead it just says "continue". What am I doing wrong? Also, I want to make the program `break` under the `System.out.println("Invalid name entered");` line, but repl.it tells me "break cannot be used outside of a loop or switch". I have to use regular expressions here by the way.

I'm not sure what to do. `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(naming);` is supposed to set the name to a pattern, then `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[^a-zA-Z]");` is supposed to look for non-letters. Finally,

```
boolean check = matcher.find();
   if (check) {
      System.out.println("Invalid name entered");
   } else {
      System.out.print("continue");
```

is supposed to print "Invalid name entered" if non-letters are found, but it just ignores that and prints "continue" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the regular expression and the string that's being searched the wrong way round.  Instead of

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(naming);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

You need something like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(naming);
```